# RecyclerView doesn't display any items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a searchview and a recyclerview. After querying search results from TheMovieDb.org API I want to display the result on the recyclerview.

Tried

1. Logging the onResponse method, it shows that it gets the data
2. Tried using ViewModel before and didn't work
3. Setting a recycler adapter inside onResponse

Here is my code

```
private static final String API_KEY = "2e08750083b7e21e96e915011d3f8e2d";
private static final String TAG = SearchAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

public Search() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    SearchView searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_result_tv);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            loadData(s);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void loadData(String s) {

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getList().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<Response> responseCall = apiInterface.getMovieSearch(API_KEY, s);
    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {

            /* Load search from String here */
            ArrayList<ResultsItem> resultsItemList;
            if (response.body() != null) {
                resultsItemList = (ArrayList<ResultsItem>) response.body().getResults();

                SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(resultsItemList, getContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

            } else {
                Log.d("NoResponse", "response null");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the adapter in the onResponse, set the adapter once and manipulate the array list that the adapter is working on. clear the list on every response and add all found items and notify the adapter

Comment: are you sure your retrofit call succeeded ? and please log the resultsItemList.

Comment: @GhifariAkbar, Are you getting data from the API as the search perfomed?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a result back? Also what thread is that happening? You must set the adapter as well as update it on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: @Ashis tried logging the resultItemList and nothing shows. guess the problem is a retrofit call. instead this showed D/SearchAdapter: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 6.2 at line 1 column 1003 path $.results[1].vote_average

Comment: @GhifariAkbar please post the log in your question.

Comment: @Ashish 2019-08-20 20:53:11.551 15784-15784/picodiploma.dicoding.database D/SearchAdapter: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 6.2 at line 1 column 1003 path $.results[1].vote_average
2019-08-20 20:53:12.054 15784-15784/picodiploma.dicoding.database D/SearchAdapter: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 6.2 at line 1 column 1003 path $.results[1].vote_average

Comment: @Ashish changing from int to float on the Response class solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

What would be better is to define your adapter before you make the API call. So like this:

```
SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(resultsItemList, getContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

Call<Responce> responceCall = //...
```

That is because you can't set the adapter off the main thread, or where your UI is. Since, however, your items when you define them would be empty, you need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Go ahead and add this function to your adapter class:

```
public void updateItems(List<Object> newItems) {
     //Set your adapter items to the new items
     adapterItems.clear()
     adapterItems.addAll(newItems);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Note that `adapterItems` is the `List<Object>` you have in your adapter class. After you have done this, you can go and update your recycler view like this:

```
if (response.body() != null) {
    resultsItemList = (ArrayList<ResultsItem>) response.body().getResults();

    searchAdapter.updateItems(resultsItemList);
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dont set adapter in on response first get data in arraylist in onresponse method. clear arraylist everytime you call onresponse and after that you should call adapter and set adapter in oncreateview.hope this will help.